# Can I get soft and updates NOT from elementary servers?

Tags: updates

My internet provider has banned elementary.io and I think all elementary servers, because I can't install anything (soft) and can't get updates too. I got a ISO of elementary just by using proxy extension in chrome. Can I change like, I don't know, mirrors when I use Elementary OS? Or it's not possible?

Comment: Hi! Have you considered using VPN for that purpose?

Comment: I will if there's no way to change the source where updates come from.